# MDX - comma-separated column to summarize values across time dimension (rows)

Tags: csv, mdx

The below MDX query

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[GM%] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Revenue] > 2
     ,
      ([Measures].[Revenue] - [Measures].[Cost]) / [Measures].[Revenue] * 100
     ,NULL
    ) 
SELECT 
  CrossJoin
  (
    LastPeriods
    (5
     ,[Date.YQM].[2018].LastChild
    )
   ,[Measures].[GM%]
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {Order([SP].Children,[Measures].[Revenue],DESC)} ON ROWS
FROM [GM_SP];
```

Gives me the following tabular output:

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frcWS.png)

---

Question: How can I add a **column** to the end that summarizes the values across the 5 Quarters?

I need this output comma-separated as it is used for rendering a sparkline within the table. (Pentaho CDE used to render).

**Example Column 7**

- row 1: 100,,,,
- row 2: 97.82535574475716, 95.83261932552514,
  96.51941349723123, 96.77026598200818, 97.85452666266234

Comment: the function GENERATE is the standard way of concatenating things in mdx